# Powershell RegEx Match Index is always the same

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm using the following code snippet to search for several system names in a text file and save them in an array.
Now, I need to save the position of the matches but just get always only the position of the first match.

```
$pattern_sysname = '(?<=Computername).+?($)'
Get-Content $path | Foreach {if ([Regex]::IsMatch($_, $pattern_sysname)) {

           $arr_sysname += [Regex]::Match($_, $pattern_sysname)

        }

            }

           $arr_sysname.index
```

I need the position of every single match.

Comment: What do you mean with position, Line number/offset? See `Select-String -Path $Path -Pattern $pattern_sysname -AllMatches` IMO enclosing the line end anchor in parentheses `($)` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

See this demo:

```
#demo data
@'
Computername12
This is Computername1
ComputernameABC
NotMatched
'@ | out-file regex.test

$pattern_sysname = '(?<=Computername).+?$'

Select-String -Path regex.test -Pattern $pattern_sysname -AllMatches |
  select LineNumber,@{N='OffsetInLine';E={$_.Matches[0].Index}}
```

*Result:*

```
LineNumber OffsetInLine
---------- ------------
         1           12
         2           20
         3           12
```